# Adding sections of cells to last columns of a table based on color index

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I'm trying to map out a project to simplify a daily task that I do every day.

My basic routine involves running through a table and identifying which columns are green in columns (M:CT).

My question is how can I loop through these rows, identify the "green columns" paste the columns to the end of each row, and add 4 rows below?

**The image below is an example of my current sheet:**
[image]

**The image below is a demonstration of what I want to have.**
  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzBtH.png): [image]

Comment: Perhaps loop backwards if you are adding rows.

Comment: Yeah that would work. How would I go about identifying and placing the green columns after column CT? @BigBen

Comment: [`Cut`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.cut) them perhaps and then place them in the next empty column, starting in CT.

Comment: Please clarify - your code counts the number of rows from A13 to the last row (which equals the last row - 13), but then you use x to loop through the range starting at row 1 to `NumRows`, which will stop 13 rows before the last row (this just doesn't make sense). Also, `ColorIndex` is  number from 1 to 56. `Color` can use standard colors like `vbRed` `vbYellow` or `vbGreen`, there is no `vbLightGreen`. Also, you are testing if the whole rows range from columns A to CR is green, is that what you want? Do you want to copy/paste the whole column to the next empty column? Again, clarify.

Comment: I fixed some of the discrepancies in the code. Basically what I need to do is loop through the rows (starting at row 13) until the row is empty, identify & copy/paste all green columns after column CT. @GMalc

Comment: @GMalc refer to the "Code Theory" section

Comment: Please update your questions with an example of your data and what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Are all cells in a column green or is only one cell green? Do you want to copy the entire column or just the green cell in the row?

Comment: I updated the above to make it simpler to see visually. @GMalc